WooCommerce shop pagination and cache
I have these hooks to add "some div" below product.
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'map_woo_template_loop_product_replaced_thumb', 10 );

function map_woo_template_loop_product_replaced_thumb($html = null) {
      echo '<div class="foo"></div>';

}

Then I have javascript enqueue file:
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'map_woo_enqueue_scripts');

function map_woo_enqueue_scripts() {

     wp_enqueue_script('map_woo', plugins_url('/source/js/foo.js, __FILE__), array());
}

In foo.js I have:
if (!/loaded|interactive|complete/.test(document.readyState)){
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initMyPlugin);
}else{
   initMyPlugin();  
} 

function initMyPlugin(){
     //this only runs on page load
 
}

The problem is if I use pagination buttons to move to second shop page, initMyPlugin does not run. The same is true if I use browser back / forward buttons to move though pagination (if browser url was already set when moving though pagination)
How can I have this code run everytime after pagination?
I am using default WordPress 2024 theme and WooCommerce,no other  plugins.
